# Регулярное выражение из консоли

Tags: perl

Нужно применить маску регулярного выражения с консоли. Т.е. в консоли пишется "Введите маску", печатается маску и по ней уже производится замена символов.

Вот что имеется:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl  
print < STDOUT >."Введите маску";  
$pattern = < STDIN >;  
$stroka = "  as df as df a sd f  f as df asdfasdf asdf";  
$stroka=~s/$pattern//g;  
print $stroka;
```

Но не получается применить маску. В чём здесь проблема?

Comment: А кто такой `$line` и откуда оно берётся?  Может `$stroka`? И, кстати, не `$pattern = < STDIN >;` , а 

      $pattern = <STDIN>;

и print <STDOUT> я уж не помню, как будет нормально.

И ещё. `$pattern` будет содержать конец строки, поэтому после

      $pattern = <STDIN>;

не помешает

      chop $pattern;

(хотя лучше `chomp $pattern;` -- безопасней)

Comment: извиняюсь, недочёт. Исправил так как надо.

Comment: ни chop, ни chomp не помогает.

Comment: @RomkaKraynov

     #!/usr/bin/perl  
     print STDOUT "Введите маску>";  
     $pattern = <STDIN>;  
     chomp $pattern;
     $stroka = "  as df as df a sd f  f as df asdfasdf asdf";  
     $stroka=~s/$pattern//g;  
     print $stroka;

     alex@ubuntu:~/tmp$ ./a.perl
     Введите маску>sd
     as df as df a  f  f as df afaf af

Comment: Без `use strict` - расстрел без права на реабилитацию :)

Comment: не помогло(

Comment: @RomkaKraynov, вы б хоть пример дали - на каких данных не работает.

Comment: Всем благодарен за ответы. Помогло chop. Проверял chomp тоже всё нормально.

Comment: @RomkaKraynov т.е. у меня код работает, у Вас -- нет? Какая ОС?

Да и вообще, приличные языки уже не подходят? нужен именно perl?

Comment: @RomkaKraynov отличите chomp от chop см. в perlfunc. Я chop в рабочих скриптах не использовал.

Comment: @RomkaKraynov, "Помогло chop"??? Помогло чему - чтобы пара строк  заработали методом случайного тыка?